# How to make checkbox clickable from its label

Tags: html, laravel-8, php-7.4

I want to make this checkbox clickable from its label!

```
<li style="display:inline;"> 
    {{ Form::checkbox('roles[]', $role->id) }}
    {{ Form::label($role->name, ucfirst($role->name)) }} |
</li>
```

How can I pass 'for' and id on it ?

Comment: Are you using a package for forms? In general, either enclose the checkbox in the label or use the `for` attribute in a label to associate it with an input

Comment: I didn't use any packages but i don't know how to pass for option in laravel collectives form::label @brombeer

Comment: So you're using LaravelCollective's package. Try `{{ Form::label($role->name, ucfirst($role->name), ['for' => 'YOURIDHERE']) }}`